# Division in C# to get exact value

Tags: c#, floating-point, integer-division

If I divide 150 by 100, I should get 1.5. But I am getting 1.0 when I divided like I did below:

```
double result = 150 / 100;
```

Can anyone tell me how to get 1.5?

Comment: look up integer division - `100` is an integer - use doubles instead

Answer (score 17):

try:

```
 double result = (double)150/100;
```

When you are performing the division as before:

```
double result = 150/100;
```

The devision is first done as an Int and then it gets cast as a double hence you get 1.0, you need to have a double in the equation for it to divide as a double.

Answer (score 10):

Cast one of the ints to a floating point type. You should look into the difference between decimal and double and decide which you want, but to use double:

```
double result = (double)150 / 100;
```

Answer (score 6):

Make the number `float`

```
var result = 150/100f
```

or you can make any of number to float by adding `.0`:

```
double result=150.0/100
```

or

```
double result=150/100.0
```

Comment: Note that adding the `.0` technically makes it a double which won't fit in a `float` (your code shows that but the text contradicts it).

Answer (score 4):

```
double result = (150.0/100.0)
```

One or both numbers should be a float/double on the right hand side of `=`

Answer (score 2):

If you're just using literal values like 150 and 100, C# is going to treat them as integers, and integer math always "rounds down". You can add a flag like "f" for float or "m" for decimal to not get integer math. So for example `result = 150m/100m` will give you a different answer than `result = 150/100`.